# The meaning of "Sunlight thrown over smashed human bones."

Tags: lyrics

It's from "The First of The Gang To Die" by Morrissey.

Is "thrown over" here mean toss something? Or is it mean abandon something?

Could you explain it to me in simple terms please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, *throw light on* is a standard phrase for *shining on something*, see [Oxford Thesaurus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/throw_(or_cast_or_shed)_light_on). In my opinion, *cast light* is more frequently used.

(I'm not entirely convinced, that this is the most appropriate section of SO, English Language comes to mind.)

Comment: But they don't need the traffic like we do :D